# How to set up gulp-svgmin in the safest way?

Tags: svg, gulp

does anyone know how to use gulp-svgmin?

I tested it with a simple svg file, but the output removed the clipPath and mask tags

input:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="hex-v" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><!--objectBoundingBox is important, so that the points becomes percentage values inside the element clipped-->
            <polygon points=".25 0, .75 0, 1 .5, .75 1, .25 1, 0 .5"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="hex-h" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><!--objectBoundingBox is important, so that the points becomes percentage values inside the element clipped-->
            <polygon points=".5 0, 1 .25, 1 .75, .5 1, 0 .75, 0 .25"/>
        </clipPath>

        <radialGradient id="gradient" r="1">
            <stop stop-color="white" offset="50%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="70%"/>
        </radialGradient>

        <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><radialGradient id="a" r="1"><stop stop-color="#fff" offset="50%"/><stop offset="70%"/></radialGradient></defs></svg>
```

So I assume it's because there are some options I should set for the svgmin?

I want svgmin to minify the files in the safest way possible, so I don't get unexpected results.

Or is there a different gulp plugin I can use?

Thanks